# Periodically rebooting a process

Tags: shell

I'm a shell noob, this is my first script in years and if this question is overly simple I apologize

I'm trying to write a shell script for our server that constantly runs and periodically reboots a specific process. Is there anything wrong with this approach? This will be added to crontab to start when the server starts

```
a=1
while [ $a == 1 ]

do
  <process name> &
  sleep 10m
  pkill <process name>
done
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to know how to implement the rebooting or alternatives to rebooting?

Comment: I'm asking if this is sufficient for rebooting, and if not how would i implement it.

Comment: When you run it does it work? What is happening that is unexpected?

Comment: It's not a **good** approach at all -- using pkill in general is a huge hammer, and there are far better tools for the job (systemd, upstart, runit, daemontools, etc. will all give you more fine-grained and more reliable tools for restarting processes). But will it work? Until you hit a bug (kill another process with an overlapping name) or need functionality it doesn't provide (like persisting through reboot), sure.

Comment: By the way, the POSIX test comparison operator is `=`, not `==`; your code is needlessly unportable for using `==`. But then, why not just `while true` or `while :`?

Answer (score 1):

I would wait for the process to be actually killed until restarting it again, to make sure you have only one of these processes running at a time:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  <process name> &
  last_pid=$!
  sleep 10m
  pkill $last_pid
  wait $last_pid
done
```

Comment: What if someone ran another process during the 10m sleep? wouldn't this kill that instead? that's why i was flagging by name

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line. The pid is unique, while the process name is not. The approach above ensures that only the process is killed that was previously started in the loop.

Comment: The PID isn't entirely unique, no; process table entries do get recycled, and this is part of why using pidfiles in places where advisory locks are more appropriate is a horrible practice. But, granted, it's more unique than the process name.

Comment: The funny thing is that in the really old days, everyone already did the right thing -- there was an `/etc/inittab` that listed processes that were supposed to be running; PID 1 ran them as its direct children, used the `wait()` call to poll for exit, and restarted anything flagged for same when it died without wasting time polling or making silly assumptions that would break if PIDs got reused. It's only after `/etc/inittab` gave way to rc.d scripts that we ended up with a mess that's only recently getting cleaned up with upstart, systemd, etc.